# How to replace double quotes with / in a string with some other value in C#

Tags: c#, html

I have image tag in my html like `img src="/images/image.jpg"`.

I want it like `src="mydomain.com/images/image.jpg"`

So I want to replace all `src="/` to `src="mydomain.com/.`
I tried this

```
                      string repto = "src=\"/" + strLink.HRef + "/";
                      strEncode.Replace("src=\"/", repto);
```

strEncode contains my html.
I tried many ways but nothing is working. Please help, if any body has any idea about this.
Thanks

Comment: _"I tried many ways"_ for instance? Also, what is this, ASP.NET, winforms(f.e. `WebBrowser`), javascript, HTML,...? Where and when do you want to modify them?

Comment: By the way - it's not a very good idea to use absolute path in html code.

Comment: Have you tried [regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/244935)?

Comment: a piece of could would be nice, otherwise you´ll get more and more down-votes.

Comment: Actually this html is coming from a feed and the path of image is relative. So i have to add domain name before the source to make it available.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
html_string.Replace("src=\"/images", "src=\"mydomain.com/images");
```

?

Comment: "not working". Aha. For my own I upvoted this as being a correct way.

Comment: Replace "html_string" with the name of your variable. Why not working?

Comment: I already replaced it, But not working I think It is not getting Escape character there.

Comment: "I think" is not enough. After replacing, why arnt you just echoing the string out to check how it looks like? I dont think the poster is responsible for every written character.

Answer (score 2):

```
string foo = @"src=\"/images/image.jpg\"";
string bar = foo.Replace("src=\"", "src=\"mydomain.com");
```

Answer (score 2):

String#Replace does not change the value of strEncode, in fact it returns a new string with the encoded value. 
So this may help you out:

```
strEncode = strEncode.Replace("src=\"/", repto);
```

Comment: An upvote or accept would be appreciated in this case